# My wp_update_nav_menu action is firing twice

Tags: plugins, menus, actions, rest-api, headless

i am trying to setup a wp_update_nav_menu action in a Plugin. Now I wonder why this is firing twice. I want to update all my pages with this hook in a headless wp implementation. And this double firing is causing a lot of unwanted requests. I wonder if someone knows how I could implement it  only firing once.

```
add_action('wp_update_nav_menu', 'after_menu_update', 10,2);
function after_menu_update($id, $data = NULL){
    error_log( var_export( 'fired' , 1 ) );
}
```

Comment: Just ran into this issue today. Hope someone has a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with sending an email after someone changes a menu. I always had 2 messages sent, as "wp_update_nav_menu", is called twice. I searched for a solution too and found nothing. My solution is not very good, but it worked for me.

```
add_action('wp_update_nav_menu',  function () {
    static $counter = 0;
    $counter++;

    if ($counter %2 === 0) {
        // some code
    }
});
```

I hope this will help someone. Or maybe someone can improve my solution.